# How to solve the given differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

> Given $T$ is a function in $t$ $(x>0)$. And $T(@t=0)=40$. And which satisfies,
> $$ \frac{dt}{4}= \frac{3\cdot dT}{2} + \frac{T\cdot dt}{400+t}$$
> Then find $T$

I tried putting $400+t=u$ and then,

$$ \frac{du}{4}= \frac{3\cdot dT}{2} + \frac{T\cdot du}{u}$$
And multiplying by $4u$ both sides gives,

$$u\cdot du= 6\cdot u\cdot dT+ 4\cdot T \cdot du$$

And by integrating by parts bay taking common $4$ gives,

$$ \frac{u^2}{2}=4\cdot u \cdot T+ \int 2\cdot u \cdot dT+c$$

But now I am stuck here. Can someone help me solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by $dt$: $$\frac{1}4=\frac{3}{2}\frac{dT}{dt}+\frac{T}{400+t}$$Multiply by $\frac{2}3$: $$\frac{1}6=\frac{dT}{dt}+\frac{\frac{2}3T}{400+t}$$Using the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524903/proof-of-ode-solution) we get $$\frac{C}{(400+t)^{2/3}}+\frac{t}{10}+40$$Solve for $C$: $$\frac{C}{400^{2/3}}+40=40\implies C=0$$So our final answer is $T(t)=\frac{t}{10}+40$

Comment: Is there a method by substitution without using formula?

Comment: @Krish I think that would be difficult because there are differentials.

Answer (score 3):

Under your substitution, the ODE becomes [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation)

$$\frac32 \, dT = \left(\frac14 - \frac T{400+t}\right) \, dt \implies \frac{dT}{du} = \frac16 \left(1-\frac{4T}u\right)$$

Further substituting $U=\frac Tu$ and $\frac{dU}{du}=\frac{u\frac{dT}{du} - T}{u^2}$ gives the separable ODE,

$$u\,\frac{dU}{du} + U = \frac{1-4U}6 \implies \frac{dU}{1-10U} = \frac{du}{6u}$$